# How can I know that I installed Oscuro's Oblivion Overhaul correctly?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I've extracted the .bsa file with OBMM into the Data folder (overwriting some things, I think), I've put the whole .bsa file, and the .esp and .esm files in there too, and the esp/esms show up in both OBMM and Data Files in the Launcher...

Still, I'm afraid that I did something wrong. How can I know it'll work properly?

Answer (score 2):

By starting the game and looking around.

Oscuro's Oblivion Overhaul is a pretty freaking huge change, there are many new enemies to fight and a lot of new armor and weapons to find. You should be able to tell in a few minutes that the new stuff is there.

That, by the way, is just making sure everything is installed correctly if the game doesn't tell you right out: If you find float exclamation marks, checkered purple/black textures or the game just right out crashes you'll also know you didn't install it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, but I've never played vanilla, how can I know the stuff is new or the levels are changed?

Comment: @AlexMitan Search Google for some of the enemies you fight or some of the items you pick up. It will be obvious which ones were part of the base game because they will show up in wiki's.

Comment: @AlexMitan Basically, if you see a huge monster, OOO *is* correctly installed.

Comment: @AlexMitan if you never played vanilla, how did you know you wanted to use OOO?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to play your game and see if it's working. If you find:

- Exclamation Marks, which represents missing meshes.
- That your game is bugged out.
- Nothing in the game that is part of the mod.
- When you load a save, it firsts tells you content isn't available before continuing.

If you find any of these things, then you haven't installed the mod correctly. Try to reinstall the mod and read the instructions carefully, then when it's done go play your game to see if it was installed correctly. Remember, this mod has a lot of stuff such as creatures, NPCs, new armor, new weapons, so it'll be easy to notice. If you installed the mod correctly, and it works, then good gaming!